# How to run a bat file in windows from linux systm

Tags: linux, batch-file, cmd, autohotkey

I recorded a certain process by autohotkey and saved as `auto.ahk` in Windows system. I need to run that from Linux system, so I created a bat file with content `start 'd:\auto.ahk'` and saved as `test.bat`. But when I use the following code in terminal, it doesn't work

```
ssh user@192.00.00.00 'd:/test'
```

Comment: I guess you you to call the `autohotkey` program explicitly: `ssh user@server -- authohotkey.exe d:/test.ahk`

Comment: autohotkey.exe means. i didn't create any exe.

Comment: Some program must execute `auto.ahk`. Call that program explicitly with `d:\auto.ahk` as argument. I was guessing the program is autohotkey.exe. If this is not the case, you'll find the program in the registry.

Comment: The problem is that SSH only gives you shell access. You'd be better off with an AHK script that's constantly running, periodically checking for the presence of a file or command and doing something useful if it's there. [Here's an example](http://lifehacker.com/5547714/launch-applications-remotely-with-dropbox-and-autohotkey) using DropBox, but using SSH for poking the file would work just as well.

Comment: What hek2mgl  would do the job in case autohotkey.exe is in the same direcotry. Otherwise you may wanna pass the complete path to autohotkey.exe

Answer (score 0):

Because of the fact that you .ahk script requires the actual autohotkey program on windows to run (it's the interpreter between raw text and binary commands to windows), what you're likely running into is that the bat file is trying to just "run" your .ahk script, but can't run a raw text file like a program. What you may be able to do to fix this is compiling your .ahk script, making it an executable. Then, you could call the executable directly, just like you would any other .exe on the computer. (you might also want to try starting any other .exe this way like notepad to make sure your method of running the program is correct)

Another solution would be, as @Matthew Strawbridge suggested, to have a script running quietly in the background of the computer, periodically checking the contents of a file that the .bat can write to. This has the added bonus of you being able to customize what the script does by what is written in the check up file.